# Drawing lines ontop of texture in Direct3D

Tags: windows-store-apps, direct3d

Im am working in Direct3d11 with Windows 8 Store apps.

I have been searching google and missing a few points, that i would be happy if someone could point out for me.

So far i have managed to created buffers, shaders and getting a texture sampled with D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST and i can ofcause change it to a LINELIST and get a line of my points.

What am I to look for when i want to draw the texture and also draw some lines or a trianglelist as lines ontop of the texture. I want to show the texture and a mesh ontop of it.

What are my next step.

Comment: Are you wanting to draw a mesh and have it's wire frame drawn on top of it?

Comment: Yes. I have found out sofar that its possible to just draw two primitive types based on the same data which looks like what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to fist render the object setting the render state to `D3D11_FILL_SOLID`. Then render the same object again but setting the render state to `D3D11_FILL_WIREFRAME`.

The "wireframe pass" shader can be very simple based on your needs, just remember to change the shading from the regular pass or else you wont be able to see the wireframe.